# Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation. React-snap

Tags: reactjs, react-snap

I'm trying to use react-snap in my react app. Using it because of some features. But I think I did not configure it well because of this error that is showing.

```
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    if (rootElement?.hasChildNodes()) {
        hydrateRoot(rootElement, APP);
    } else {
        const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
        root.render(APP)
    }
```

```
"scripts": {
    "postbuild": "react-snap"
},
"reactSnap": {
    "include": [
        "/link1",
        "/link2",
        "/link3",
        "/link4",
        "/link5",
        "/link6"
     ],
    "fixWebpackChunksIssue": "CRA1"
},
```

The error that I'm getting is this

```
Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation
```